# using underscore library with wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, underscore.js

I'm using underscore library for array manipulation. I enqueued the library with the following code in my functions.php

```
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jt_enqueue_scripts' );

    function jt_enqueue_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-util' );
    }
```

But when i try using it in my code, i get reference error stating underscore is not defined.

```
$json = json_decode($response_body);
$items =  _.map($json,'items'); // throws error:'_' is not defined
echo '<script>console.log('.$items.')</script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is from an old tutorial and some things have changed in WP.

So the way underscore is imported now is through a `load-scripts.php`, it has a GET parameter what to load. So underscore isn't in the wp-util file it is in its separate file `\wp-includes\js\underscore.min.js`

Here is how to include it:

`wp_enqueue_script('undescore', includes_url('js') . '/underscore.min.js' );`

Documentation for `includes_url` on [devoloper.wordpress.org](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/includes_url/)

**Edit (another option)**

As I stated above, WP uses the `load-scripts.php` file to load scripts from include, you can use this: 
`http://localhost/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?load=underscore`

You can add a `c=` parameter for compression.

**I don't recommend this method, use the above stated with *enqueue scripts*!!!**

Comment: I tried using what you mentioned. It still gives me the same error - Use of undefined constant _ and use of undefined function map(). Also, when i type in '_.VERSION' in the console i get the version number as 1.8.3 but when i type the same thing on the page where my plugin is running i get undefined '__' error

Comment: I have tested this before posting. https://i.imgur.com/8cwtC15.png

You would have to explain what are you trying to achieve and what you mean by "where my plugin is running".

Comment: I created a short code for my plugin. I enqueued the script in functions.php first and it didn't work. I tried enqueuing it in my plugin code, that didn't work either but i do get version number on pages where i've not included my short code (like the screenshot you posted). On pages where my shortcode for my plugin is posted i get undefined '_' error.

Comment: First of all, it is not nice to not include your whole code or fully describe it. Because we can't properly answer the question. The solution I provided above is correct but not for your situation because you are developing a plugin and calling some kind of hooks that renders before the script.

So to answer your problem check to which hook you are calling the `echo '<script>...` because that is your problem. Example if you added the echo to the init hook or any other it will render it before the <DOCTYPE>. Here is a proof that it works once again https://i.imgur.com/bMuIdBI.png